# What title of space movie where girl's hologram asks: “to be or not be that's the question”?

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship, computers

A sci-fi movie maybe from 90s, where cargo spaceship with some people on it that try to unlock spaceship computer that has recorded women hologram that asks various questions and riddles, one of them "to to be or not be that's the question". Big cargo spaceship maybe has Chinese like name. 
Please help to identify the title.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_pirates

Comment: Are you sure it was a spaceship and not some kind of building?

Comment: @Richard - Yeah, I'm sure. Dark, big spaceship, maybe Chinese, don't remember the name of the ship but it was complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be [The Apocalypse](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118631/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_35).
The (at least partly) crazy programmer that locked the ship's computer with those riddles was played by Laura San Giacomo.
The cargo spaceship has a load of nuclear weapons and is on collision course with earth.

### Trailer

At the 1:59 point in the trailer, you get a Shakespeare quote, albeit "[All's Well that Ends Well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All%27s_Well_That_Ends_Well)."

Comment: at last)) yes, this is it! thank you very much!